# How to configure the database tables with Fluent?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Iam trying to generate the tables of the database but the tables are not generated.
I'm doing the mapping like this:

```
using Domain.Entidades;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Domain.Infraestrutura
{
    public class Conexao
    {
        public static void CriarTabelasBanco()
        {

            FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey("psConnection")).ShowSql())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
                .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Pessoa>());

            configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your mappings first and then call ExposeConfiguration, otherwise the mappings are not known to the config at the point you call the SchemaExport.

Apart from that, `SchemaExport` fails silently, so if there are any errors, it will not throw and exception, instead you can have a look into the exceptions list of the SchemaExport instance, therefore you would have to structure the call slightly different.